# SELinux Centos Symfony and Docker - File Permissions

Tags: linux, command-line, permissions, docker

I am trying to change the permissions of two files in a docker container following the Symfony permission's guide using `docker-compose exec` command:

```
docker-compose exec --user root fpm sh -c "setfacl -dR -m u:www-data:rwX -m u:root:rwX var"

docker-compose exec --user root fpm sh -c "setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rwX -m u:root:rwX var"
```

But I get the response:

```
setfacl: var: Permission denied
```

According to https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/exec/ I can pass the `--privileged` option to "Give extended privileges to the process." this seems to have no effect.

How do I sudo this command?

Comment: Did you try using `sudo docker-compose exec`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: SELinux doesn't work with docker on Centos 7.3.

This turned out to be SELinux denying access to the file. I checked the SELinux labels inside my var/ directory with:

```
ls -latZ
```

This returned:

```
drwxrwxr-x+ user user unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 logs
drwxrwxr-x+ user user unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 cache
```

These are correct (see the **httpd_sys_rw_content_t** part)

Learn more about SELinux here (easy read with visuals): https://opensource.com/business/13/11/selinux-policy-guide

So then I tried to enable the SELinux docker module with:

```
semodule -v -e docker
```

This failed with:

```
Re-declaration of type docker_t
Failed to create node
Bad type declaration at /etc/selinux/targeted/tmp/modules/100/docker/cil:1
semodule:  Failed!
```

Searched that 'bad type' part of the error and found the bug in github here:
https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/28406

To find your release number do:

```
cat /etc/centos-release
```